# How to enable teamcity agent for Build Tools 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity-8.0

Im trying to make a build of asp.net mvc 4 application on my teamcity server.

The server is Windows Server 2012 R2. with 64bit OS.
Teamcity version is 8.1 (build 29879).

If I set MSBuild version to MSBuild Tools 2013 agent is incompatible. 
The reason is: `Unmet requirements: MSBuildTools12.0_x64_Path exists`

I made sure I install .net sdk, and as its a Windows Server 2012, .net 4.5 is already 
 installed there (4.5.2 in my case). What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you installed the [Build Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40760)? They [no longer come with the .NET framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio.aspx), part of Windows or not, but with the Studio or as a standalone installer. Don't forget to restart afterwards.

Comment: Build tools and SDK, both installed.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev You sure? I just spawned a vanilla Win2012R2x64 VM, installed TC #29879, got an incompatible agent with missing `MSBuildTools12.0_x64_Path`, then simply installed `BuildTools_Full`, restarted the agent service and voila, parameter now exists. May be your build config is set up to use the wrong agent pool?

Comment: How do I check on this? After I installed the SDK I disabled and enabled the agent, is that sufficient, or I need to do something else to restat it?

Comment: Yes, after agent machine reboot it worked. Thanks for the help!